# Redirecting minecraft port to another

Tags: networking, dns, port, minecraft, record

We are transferring our Minecraft server to a different host and there's a pretty good chance, that it will be running on a different port.

I currently have two records on the server website:

`mc.domain.sk   CNAME   {ServerIP}`

`_minecraft._tcp.mc.domain.sk   SRV     5 25560 mc.domain.sk`

So just changing the port in the SRV record should be fine. But here's the catch - many players have been connecting to our server using the port too. Basically using `mc.domain.sk:25560` instead of just `mc.domain.sk`. Is there any way to forward this 25560 port to another port (f.e. 25561)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, CNAME **must NOT point to an IP**. It must point to another domain name, so unless you mis-wrote the question, your setup is incorrect.

> Is there any way to forward this 25560 port to another port?

Is any downtime acceptable? If yes, then it's easy just spawn a proxy (nginx) at that domain and that port, and redirect all incoming traffic to another domain and another port.

If downtime is not acceptable, then you need somehow to migrate active connections between hosts. Even if you manage to do this at IP/TCP level, I don't know if your application will be able to handle this correctly. Cannot help on that.